# Call api in store from controller. Ext Js

Tags: extjs

I have this function inside my controller which works when clicking the button:

```
 onSaveClick: function () {
    var form = this.lookupReference('userForm');

    if (form.isValid()) {

        //form.getValues();
    }
},
```

I want to pass the values to my store which has the following code:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: '/api/Users',
    api: {
        create: '/Users/PostUser',
        read: '/Users/GetListUsers',
        update: '/Users/PutUser',
        destroy: '/Users/DeleteUser'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: false
    }
}
```

I want to call the api create and pass my data from the controller. How do I do this? I'm very new to Sencha ExtJs.

Comment: Where is your store defined?

Comment: app -> store -> UserStore.js

Comment: If your UserStore has a `storeId` config you can get a reference with `var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('userStore')`; then call `store.load({ params: form.getValues() });`

Comment: I'm going to do a api create.. i will still use store.load? sorry for too much questions

Comment: You will probably only need the params while loading the store right? Maybe you could create a fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com) with what you are trying to do we could help you from there

Comment: uhmm, i'm afraid I can't coz I don't know how, well anyway, I did add storeId, to my store, and add the reference in my controller but i'm getting Cannot read property 'load' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

First you need to **add the record** in the store and then you can call `sync()` on store which will call the **create api** as Ext finds that there is a new record added to the store.

```
 Ext.getStore('<yourStoreId>').add(form.getValues()); // adding the record to the store
 Ext.getStore('<yourStoreId>').sync(); // it will call create api as we have a new record added
```

**Sample Code:**

```js
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpleStore',
      fields : ['first','last'],
      proxy: {
      type: 'rest',
    url: '/api/Users',
    api: {
        create: '/Users/PostUser',
        read: '/Users/GetListUsers',
        update: '/Users/PutUser',
        destroy: '/Users/DeleteUser'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: false
    }
}
});
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Form',
       // The fields
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'first',
        allowBlank: false
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'last',
        allowBlank: false
    }],

    // Reset and Submit buttons
    buttons: [ {
        text: 'Submit',
        handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if (form.isValid()) {
             Ext.getStore('simpleStore').add(form.getValues());
             Ext.getStore('simpleStore').sync();
            }
        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
}
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm getting error on this part it's returning undefined even if my storeId is myUserStore 
var userStore = Ext.getStore('myUserStore');

Comment: as I checked your syntax, it's correct http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.data.StoreManager.html. but the doc is for ext js 4.0, i guess it's no longer working for 6.5.1?

Comment: but this doc https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/src/StoreManager.js.html shows the way you get the store, but i still get undefined

Comment: I tried it ext 6.5 also, it worked for me. Need to see your code to understand your problem